# Where to look for Agent history in Replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-agent, high-availability

In SQL server 2008R2 replication configuration, "agent history cleanup distribution" job by default runs every 10 minutes and deletes any historical data older the 48hrs. If I increase the retention parameter for > 48hrs to access that historical data, where will that data be saved by default ?

Answer (score 3):

> where will that data be saved by default ?

`Agent history clean up: distribution` calls

```
EXEC [distribution_db_name].dbo.sp_MShistory_cleanup @history_retention = 48
```

This PROC deletes from `MSsnapshot_history` , `MSlogreader_history`, `MSdistribution_history`, `MSqreader_history` and `MSmerge_history` and bunch of other tables.

This is the entire code for a ready reference :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MShistory_cleanup
(
    @history_retention int = 24
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cutoff_time datetime
                ,@replerr_cutoff datetime
                ,@start_time datetime
                ,@num_snapshot_rows int
                ,@num_logreader_rows int
                ,@num_distribution_rows int
                ,@num_replerror_rows int
                ,@num_queuereader_rows int
                ,@num_alert_rows int
                ,@num_tracer_record_rows int
                ,@num_milliseconds int
                ,@num_seconds float
                ,@seconds_str nvarchar(10)
                ,@rate int
                ,@retcode int
                ,@total_rows int
                ,@num_merge_rows int
                ,@num_merge_deleted_articlehistory int
                ,@agent_name nvarchar(255)
                ,@agent_type nvarchar(100)
                ,@message nvarchar(255)
                ,@agent_id int
                ,@error int

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Check for invalid parameter values
    IF @history_retention < 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14106, 16, -1)
        RETURN 1
    END

    -- Get start time for statistics at the end
    -- Get cutoff time
    -- cleanup MSrepl_error with HistoryRetention+30 days
    SELECT @start_time                          = getdate(),
            @num_snapshot_rows                  = 0,
            @num_logreader_rows                 = 0,
            @num_distribution_rows              = 0,
            @num_merge_rows                     = 0,
            @num_replerror_rows                 = 0,
            @num_queuereader_rows               = 0,
            @num_merge_deleted_articlehistory   = 0,
            @cutoff_time                        = dateadd(hour, -@history_retention, getdate()),
            @replerr_cutoff                     = dateadd(hour, -@history_retention - 30*24, getdate())

    DECLARE #crSnapshotAgents CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT id
            FROM MSsnapshot_agents

    OPEN #crSnapshotAgents

    FETCH #crSnapshotAgents INTO @agent_id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN

        -- Delete sp_MSsnapshot_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
        DELETE MSsnapshot_history 
            WHERE agent_id = @agent_id
                AND time <= @cutoff_time 
                AND timestamp not in (SELECT max(timestamp) 
                                        FROM MSsnapshot_history 
                                        WHERE agent_id = @agent_id)
            OPTION(MAXDOP 1)

        SELECT @error = @@error, @num_snapshot_rows = @num_snapshot_rows + @@rowcount
        IF @error <> 0
            GOTO FAILURE

        FETCH #crSnapshotAgents INTO @agent_id
    END

    CLOSE #crSnapshotAgents
    DEALLOCATE #crSnapshotAgents

    -- Delete sp_MSsnapshot_history that no longer has an MSsnapshot_agent entry
    DELETE FROM MSsnapshot_history 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM MSsnapshot_agents
                            WHERE id = agent_id)
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_snapshot_rows = @num_snapshot_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete sp_MSlogreader_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
    DECLARE #crLogreaderAgents CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT id
            FROM MSlogreader_agents

    OPEN #crLogreaderAgents

    FETCH #crLogreaderAgents INTO @agent_id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN

        -- Delete sp_MSsnapshot_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
        DELETE MSlogreader_history 
            WHERE agent_id = @agent_id
                AND time <= @cutoff_time 
                AND timestamp not in (SELECT max(timestamp) 
                                        FROM MSlogreader_history 
                                        WHERE agent_id = @agent_id)
            OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
        SELECT @error = @@error, @num_logreader_rows = @num_logreader_rows + @@rowcount
        IF @error <> 0
            GOTO FAILURE

        FETCH #crLogreaderAgents INTO @agent_id
    END

    CLOSE #crLogreaderAgents
    DEALLOCATE #crLogreaderAgents

    -- Delete sp_MSlogreader_history that no longer has an MSlogreader_agent entry
    DELETE FROM MSlogreader_history 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM MSlogreader_agents
                            WHERE id = agent_id)
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_logreader_rows = @num_logreader_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete sp_MSdistribution_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
    DECLARE #crDistribAgents CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT id
            FROM MSdistribution_agents

    OPEN #crDistribAgents

    FETCH #crDistribAgents INTO @agent_id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN

        -- Delete sp_MSsnapshot_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
        DELETE MSdistribution_history 
            WHERE agent_id = @agent_id
                AND time <= @cutoff_time 
                AND timestamp not in (SELECT max(timestamp) 
                                        FROM MSdistribution_history 
                                        WHERE agent_id = @agent_id)
            OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
        SELECT @error = @@error, @num_distribution_rows = @num_distribution_rows + @@rowcount
        IF @error <> 0
            GOTO FAILURE

        FETCH #crDistribAgents INTO @agent_id
    END

    CLOSE #crDistribAgents
    DEALLOCATE #crDistribAgents

    -- Delete sp_MSlogreader_history that no longer has an MSlogreader_agent entry
    DELETE FROM MSdistribution_history 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM MSdistribution_agents
                            WHERE id = agent_id)
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_distribution_rows = @num_distribution_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete MSqreader_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
    DECLARE #crQreaderAgents CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT id
            FROM MSqreader_agents

    OPEN #crQreaderAgents

    FETCH #crQreaderAgents INTO @agent_id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN

        -- Delete sp_MSsnapshot_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
        DELETE MSqreader_history 
            WHERE agent_id = @agent_id
                AND time <= @cutoff_time 
                AND timestamp not in (SELECT max(timestamp) 
                                        FROM MSqreader_history 
                                        WHERE agent_id = @agent_id)
            OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
        SELECT @error = @@error, @num_queuereader_rows = @num_queuereader_rows + @@rowcount
        IF @error <> 0
            GOTO FAILURE

        FETCH #crQreaderAgents INTO @agent_id
    END

    CLOSE #crQreaderAgents
    DEALLOCATE #crQreaderAgents

    -- Delete sp_MSlogreader_history that no longer has an MSlogreader_agent entry
    DELETE FROM MSqreader_history 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM MSqreader_agents
                            WHERE id = agent_id)
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_queuereader_rows = @num_queuereader_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete sp_MSmerge_history (leave at least one row for monitoring)
    -- Leave last record ONLY if the agent is not anonymous.  The current logic is to remove all history for anonymous
    -- subscription, the agent definition will also be removed below.
    -- use session id
    DELETE dbo.MSmerge_history
        FROM dbo.MSmerge_history msmh
            JOIN dbo.MSmerge_sessions msms 
                ON msmh.session_id = msms.session_id
        WHERE msms.end_time <= @cutoff_time
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_merge_rows = @num_merge_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete sp_MSmerge_history that no longer has an MSmerge_agent entry
    DELETE FROM dbo.MSmerge_history 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM dbo.MSmerge_agents 
                            WHERE id = agent_id)
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_merge_rows = @num_merge_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete MSrepl_error entries
    DELETE FROM MSrepl_errors 
        WHERE time <= @replerr_cutoff 
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_replerror_rows = @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- similiar to above time based cleanup, we need to clean up added tables
    DELETE dbo.MSmerge_articlehistory
        FROM dbo.MSmerge_articlehistory msmah 
            JOIN dbo.MSmerge_sessions msms
                ON msmah.session_id = msms.session_id
        WHERE msms.end_time <= @cutoff_time
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_merge_deleted_articlehistory = @num_merge_deleted_articlehistory + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    DELETE FROM dbo.MSmerge_sessions 
        WHERE end_time <= @cutoff_time
            AND session_id NOT IN (SELECT max(session_id) 
                                    from dbo.MSmerge_sessions 
                                    group by agent_id)
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_merge_rows = @num_merge_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete MSmerge_sessions that no longer has an MSmerge_agent entry
    DELETE FROM dbo.MSmerge_sessions 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM dbo.MSmerge_agents 
                            WHERE id = agent_id)
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_merge_rows = @num_merge_rows + @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete sysreplicationalerts table
    DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysreplicationalerts 
        WHERE time <= @cutoff_time 
        OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
    SELECT @error = @@error, @num_alert_rows = @@rowcount
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Delete Tracer Record history rows
    EXEC @error = sys.sp_MSdelete_tracer_history @cutoff_date = @cutoff_time, @num_records_removed = @num_tracer_record_rows output
    IF @error <> 0
        GOTO FAILURE

    -- Calculate statistics for number of rows deleted
    SELECT @num_milliseconds = datediff(millisecond, @start_time, getdate())
    IF @num_milliseconds <> 0
        SELECT @num_seconds = @num_milliseconds*1.0/1000
    ELSE
        SELECT @num_seconds = 0

    SELECT @total_rows = @num_merge_rows + 
                            @num_merge_deleted_articlehistory +
                            @num_snapshot_rows + 
                            @num_logreader_rows + 
                            @num_distribution_rows +  
                            @num_queuereader_rows +
                            @num_replerror_rows + 
                            @num_alert_rows + 
                            @num_tracer_record_rows

    IF @num_seconds <> 0 
        SELECT @rate = @total_rows/@num_seconds
    ELSE
        SELECT @rate = @total_rows

    SELECT @seconds_str = CONVERT(nchar(10), @num_seconds)

    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_merge_rows, 'MSmerge_history')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_merge_deleted_articlehistory, 'MSmerge_articlehistory')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_snapshot_rows, 'MSsnapshot_history')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_logreader_rows, 'MSlogreader_history')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_distribution_rows, 'MSdistribution_history')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_queuereader_rows, 'MSqreader_history')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_replerror_rows, 'MSrepl_errors')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_alert_rows, 'sysreplicationalerts')
    RAISERROR(14108, 10, -1, @num_tracer_record_rows, 'MStracer_tokens')
    RAISERROR(14149, 10, -1, @total_rows, @seconds_str, @rate)

    RETURN 0
FAILURE:
    -- Raise the Agent Failure error
    SELECT @agent_type  = formatmessage(20544),
            @agent_name = db_name() + @agent_type,
            @message    = formatmessage(20553)

    EXEC sys.sp_MSrepl_raiserror @agent_type, @agent_name, 5, @message

    RETURN 1
END
```

Comment: Thank you, as a best practice would you suggest to keep the retention period more than 48hrs ? keeping it for a long time will consume space

Comment: Depends on how your replication is configured - continuous or some specific interval. Why is space a concerned ?

Comment: I mean, It might affect the distribution database performance and also distribution db log file growth might increase... I was planning to configure the retention period for 5days so trying to understand the consequences